# Regulations about collecting data from software running at clients hardware (apps 'phoning home')

Tags: c#, design, .net, data, sql-server

We develop an application which has now been installed on a few thousand customers sites.

Unfortunately, we have no customer data collection built into the software. This is something we want to implement in the next version. We want to collect a few parameters from the software (what features they are using), as well as ask the user who installs the software to type in their company details so we can contact them if required.

I know similar products on the market do this, however, I don't know what the regulations are. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction or gives some guidance on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you based, and where is your software installed?

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc UK based company. Most of our customers are here in the UK and quite a few in South Africa. Our US customer base is far smaller but growing steadily.

Comment: Not sure if this is good place, or if moving it to [law.stackexchange.com](http://law.stackexchange.com) is better?

Comment: Is this a question for regulations (legal, out of scope) or for the different formats for representing phone numbers (internationalization, in scope)?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch this is more of a legal question but the use case is 'collecting personal and non-personally identifiable data'.

Comment: @Shaun5, I know you already have your answer, but the suggested site of law.stackexchange.com would have been a better location for this question.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I agree, thank you for the recommendation. I will certainly consult law.stachexchange.com once we have made progress on this project. Thank you for the follow-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are UK-based you are subject to the GDPR. This regulation may or may not apply, depending on whether you are processing personal data (e.g. of customers or customer's employees), where personal data is defined by the regulation. Start by reading the [GDPR Guide](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/) of the Information Commissioner's Office.

Earlier this year your company has likely already been required to work on GDPR compliance, in particular if your clients needed to sign data processing agreements with you. If so, your proposed changes would be a continuation of this compliance effort and the people involved then may be able to help now. You may need to amend the DPAs with your clients or sign them for the first time before you start collecting any personal data.

Of course, these GDPR concerns doesn't apply if your data collection does not involve personal data – though if you collect some kind of telemetry from an app, it is unlikely that you would be exempt. Completely anonymized feature usage statistics might be fine – but consider checking with your legal counsel first. Even if the GDPR doesn't apply, you may need to consider your contracts with your customers. These contracts might not authorize you to collect any data.

In the end, this is a legal question, not primarily about software engineering. If you are a developer it is important to raise these issues, but you are likely not qualified to solve them yourself.

Comment: GDPR also applies if you're based in US or elsewhere in the world, but your software gets installed in the EU and phones home personal data from the customer's site.

Comment: @amon, thank you for your response. I think the best thing to start with will be to compile a list of all the data we want to collect and then review it with the GDPR guide you linked (get a 3rd party to review it). I'm not a regulatory expect so I appreciate your answer.